# Explicitly demonstrating Stokes' theorem over a tetrahedron.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Consider the vector field: $$\vec{F} = \left(2x-y,-yz^2,-y^2z\right)$$ We are to explicitly show stokes theorem: $$\oint_\Gamma \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} = \int\int_{\partial V}\nabla \times \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{A}$$ Where $\partial V$ is the open surface defined by the tetrahedron with vertices at $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and the face on $z=0$ being open such that $\Gamma$ is this perimeter.

Now I can't seem to calculate the double integral. I get $\nabla \times \vec{F} = (0,0,1)$ and so the faces on the $xz$ and $yz$ planes give zero, but I cannot get the contribution from the face which is the plane $x+y+z=1$, in other words, I can't seem to compute the surface integral over this plane. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Look for the projection of the surface on the xy plane. That should do it.

Comment: @Mann thanks very much, didn't realise we could project the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One result of stokes theorem is that you can change your surface of integration as long as its boundary (lip/lid whatever you call it) is not changed. So we will surface integrate the open face.

$$\int _0 ^1 \int _ 0 ^{1-x}1 \,dx\,dy $$

$$\frac12$$

Comment: Interesting! I assume this applies for all vector fields?

Comment: I can't say that confidently. Perhaps it does not work for fields with singularities. Second Page|Second Example: http://www.math.jhu.edu/~lindblad/211/l20.pdf

Comment: I see, thanks very much for the info. This trick will be extremely useful in the future, no doubt.